# Why am I NOT getting value when I execute the decrypt method on my python code?

Tags: rsa, encryption-asymmetric

After to generate a pear of assimetric **RSA keys**, I have a python code method to `encrypt` and `decrypt` string text, but decrypt value don't bring me the value what I pretend.

When I execute for *value == 1*, it works well, but when I try to execute with *value == 0*, it doesn't give any result.

```
def enc_pubK(value, txt, path_chv_pub = None, path_chv_priv = None):
        
        
        if value == 1:
            
            if path_chv_pub:
            
                with open(str(path_chv_pub), 'rb') as arq_pub:
                    
                    chave_publica = RSA.import_key(arq_pub.read())
                    cipher = PKCS1_OAEP.new(chave_publica)
                    negocio = cipher.encrypt(txt.encode())
                    print(negocio)
                    
        if value == 0:
            
            if path_chv_priv:
                
                with open(str(path_chv_priv), "rb") as arq_pri:
                    cha_pri = RSA.import_key(arq_pri.read())
                    decipher = PKCS1_OAEP.new(cha_pri)
                    vigor = decipher.decrypt(txt.decode())
                    print(vigor)
```

Comment: Your example is missing important information like what the values of `txt` are for decryption. However, if the `txt` value for decryption is exactly the value you print out after encryption then your decrypt method will certainly raise an exception at this line: `vigor = decipher.decrypt(txt.decode())` because `txt` is not the encoding of a string. If by some miracle `txt.decode()` succeeds then `decrypt` will raise an exception because it expects a bytes object, not a string.

Comment: Thanks for your attention dear @President James K. Polk! According your observation. Lets consider ''txt'' a plain text like a **AES-256 KEY**, it means if value == 1, and a string encrypted **AES-256 KEY**, if value == 0. So, I hope to give you enougth information. Congrats!